# Hawk monitoring for Tibco BW6

Tags: monitoring, tibco

Is it possible to write rules for sending alerts when an app node or an app space starts or stops.If yes, which method from the list can be used for the same?

Comment: Hi, could you update the question with the BW6 version, Hawk version and OS you are using? There are slight improvements in the newer versions for Hawk monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

It's should be simple, use below method of the appnode

**AppNodeRuntimeStateInfo**

of the Appnode check it's status , if it is running send an alert.